# C : Array Index to Pointer conversion formula for two dimension array

Tags: arrays, pointers

Explain this array index to pointer conversion formula for two dimension array :

**a[i][j] = *((base type *)a+(i * row length)+j)**

Please explain what does it mean by **(base type*)** and why it is used?

Thank You.

Comment: Where have you got this? Start with one dimension, it have the same words in its formula.

Comment: in Herbert Schildt's book : C - The Complete Reference.

Comment: Quick googling this pdf and searching it for "base type" shown that your book have the answer for your question. Page 54 in fourth edition.

Comment: It just tells the meaning of "base type". It does't explain why base type has been used in that formula.